# How can i write socket based application using dlib c++ library?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, dlib

i want to start socket programming with c++ language and dlib c++ library. but there is no complete guide in dlib.net website. is there someone can help me in socket programming in c++ with dlib library? i dont want to make my software with .net framework cause i want to write a portable app

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of socket programming examples on the [dlib website](http://dlib.net/api.html#sockets).  These are complete example programs meant to introduce different programming concepts.  Just click on any of the links to the right of "Example Programs:".  There is also a whole page for the higher level networking tools in dlib at http://dlib.net/network.html.